# Deploying a website - an error occurs - react js

Tags: reactjs, deployment, manifest.json

When deploying a website an error occurs in `manifiest.json`

```
GET https://sgfinserve.com/static/css/main.0d81c701.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://sgfinserve.com/static/js/main.95ccb7a8.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://sgfinserve.com/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the folder structure:

[image]

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

This is `manifest.json` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

And this is the `.htaccess` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <title>SG Finserve</title>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meanmenu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boxicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <link href="css/circle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

See the `index.html` markup in screenshot above.

When deploying, the error is shown.

[image]

Comment: Deploying to where?  How are you deploying?  Did you do a `build` before doing the deploy, because it is the `build` output that you would deploy and NOT the React source files.